# Change Message Dialogue box Display layout when app default language is set to ar(Arabic)?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, cultureinfo

I am creating a Windows 8 App and have set Default language as ar(Arabic). As shown below in snapshot:
[image]

Now when any Message is displayed in the Message Dialogue box its displaying in Arabic Format (Right to left). How can I change the displaying format without changing App Default language.
Message is displayed as shown below:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the  Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "en" and then when the Message Dialogue is displayed then changed  Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "ar" back.

Comment: no other way to change flow direction? even in UWP?